# Does Spring Cloud Gateway support large file responses from upstream?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a service that serves large files more than 100 MB.

I've tried to setup Spring Cloud Gateway with routes and predicates: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway

Also tried ProxyExchange: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi__building_a_simple_gateway_using_spring_mvc_or_webflux.html

Both ways cannot serve a large file:

```
org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException: Exceeded limit on max bytes to buffer : 2097152
    at org.springframework.core.io.buffer.LimitedDataBufferList.raiseLimitException(LimitedDataBufferList.java:98) ~[spring-core-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
```

And even if I increase the limit up to 10 MB it is not enough.

Does Spring Cloud Gateway support large file responses from upstream? Is it possible to stream such a response and do not try to load it all to memory?

Comment: It should. Can you provide your build information and configuration?

Comment: Added response, it seems only ProxyExchange does not work. I've managed to setup gateway routes, they work out of the box

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it turns out that only `ProxyExchange` cannot work with large responses, while regular Gateway configuration handles them:

```
@RestController
class DownloadController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/proxy", produces = "application/gzip")
    public Mono<? extends ResponseEntity<?>> proxy(ProxyExchange<byte[]> proxy) {
        // Does not support large files
        return proxy.uri("https://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/5.x/x86/release/distribution_files/core.gz")
                .sensitive()
                .forward();
    }
}

@Configuration
class GatewayConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator configure(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        // Supports Large files
        return builder.routes()
                .route(predicateSpec -> predicateSpec.path("/gateway")
                        .filters(gatewayFilterSpec -> gatewayFilterSpec.setPath("/tinycorelinux/5.x/x86/release/distribution_files/core.gz"))
                        .uri("https://distro.ibiblio.org"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you have to do something to make it work? I tried the getting started guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/gateway/ but when I add the test `stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/get")).willReturn(aResponse().withBody(new byte[256*1024 + 1])));` i get a DataBufferLimitException

Comment: Nevermind, tried the configuration in the answer and it works. But the unit test still fails for some reason.